# Gmail show inbox and sent emails in propper order

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

I'm trying to create a logic that pulls from Gmail latest unique threads using Gmail API. For this i'm using search query that looks like this:

```
subject:(-"***") (label:sent OR label:inbox)
```

And it works fine in Google's email dashboard. For my dashboard it shows different result. I'm using methods **listThreads** and **listMessages**.

For **listThreads** if thread started long ago i wont see this thread in latest messages if i or other person continue this thread (reply on an email, for example), so i have to search it on the next pages. However on Google's dashboard it will be displayed on the first page.

For **listMessages** threads will be displayed in propper order but if this thread has 2 or more messages Gmail API will return 2 or more douplicated threds.

Is there a way i can preoritize sorting by latest message date when i use **listThreads** method. Or specify my search query to return messages with unique **threadId** for **listMessages**. Or there is a different way to implement my logic?

p.s. If i use `in:inbox` in search query for **listThreads** method, I'm getting propper results, but no inbox messages which is desirable.

Here is an image example for listThreads method:
[image]

And for ListMessages:

```
{
   "id": "163d68e0ac012e74",
   "threadId": "163d67b14457c9bd"
  },
  {
   "id": "163d688dbe1c6a5e",
   "threadId": "163d67b14457c9bd"
  },
  {
   "id": "163d68743cb38393",
   "threadId": "163d67b14457c9bd"
  },
  {
   "id": "163d684f32417253",
   "threadId": "163d67b14457c9bd"
  },
  {
   "id": "163d67b14457c9bd",
   "threadId": "163d67b14457c9bd"
  },
```

As you can see they have same threadId

Comment: Have you tested calling the method using try it now in [Users.messages: list]() and [Users.threads: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list)?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 yes it has the same results as in my dashboard. you can see examples i just added as update to question.